# Change the lookup paths for Rails partial based on model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I currently have some template code like so:

```
render partial: 'reference', locals: { object: object }
```

Rails looks for the partial `_reference.html.erb` in `app/views/application/` and `app/views/controller_name/`.

However, this view is in a standalone controller, not related to the `object` being rendered, so it *doesn’t* look in the object’s view directory `app/views/object`. I can’t use the standard `render object` syntax and have Rails automagically figure out the partial path because I don’t want to render the `object/object` partial, but the `object/reference` partial.

How can I get round this?

I’m thinking either:

- Some way to use the `render object` syntax but specify a different partial name; or
- A helper function to find the partial using a different approach, used something like:

  ```
  render partial: find_partial('reference', object), locals: { object: object }
  ```

**What I’ve tried**

I tried to get the second approach working using:

```
def find_partial(name, object)
  lookup_context.find name, [object.class.model_name.plural, 'application'], true
end
```

This is *very* close to doing what I want, i.e. it finds the correct partial, and falls back to the generic `application/reference` if there isn’t one. However, it finds the actual `ActionView::Template`, and `render` is expecting a string and not the actual template object. Perhaps there’s a way to get the correct string out? Or to render an actual template?

Answer (score 7):

You can override the `to_partial_path` method in your model, this method is what gets called by render to determine which partial path to render for this model.

For example in your Model.rb

```
def to_partial_path
  "references/#{kind}"
end
```

Reference: 
http://cookieshq.co.uk/posts/rails-tips-to-partial-path/
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Conversion/to_partial_path

Comment: I like it. Unfortunately in other cases I do use the regular `render object` approach, and my question above relates to an exception. I wonder if there is any way to pass an argument via the call to `render` which will reach `to_partial_path`?

Comment: If you pass variables along with render `render object, var: "value"` they will be passed along to the partial rendered by `to_partial_path`. If you need some logic in `to_partial_path` to determine what partial to render you can depend on the model properties for that not pass variables from the view (IMHO this is better from an architectural point-of-view)

Comment: Hmm, it’s a tricky one. On the site you link to, the partial being rendered is clearly determined by some quality of the domain object. In my use case I think it’s really the view that determines the desired partial, but you’re right I don’t want logic in the partial itself. I’m using the decorator pattern in some places, and I think overriding `to_partial_path` in the decorator might be a good compromise. Still needs extra config though, telling the decorator that it’s a reference when it gets instantiated.

Comment: You could use `prepend_view_path` and add a custom path to the list rails uses when looking up views.

Answer (score 4):

Here's something that works for me: in the controller,

```
before_action :set_lookup_prefixes

def set_lookup_prefixes
  lookup_context.prefixes << "special_folder"
end
```

That just appends it, but you could inject your path anywhere you like in the `prefixes` array.

**Caveat:** I found this by rooting around in the source of the `ActionView::LookupContext` class, it's not part of the API and could be subject to change.

Comment: Upvoted but i endend up using something like this `lookup_context.prefixes |= Array("special_folder")` to avoid appending the same path more than once to the lookup_context

Answer (score 1):

This isn’t terribly elegant, but I have a working solution calling this in the view:

```
render partial: find_partial(:reference, object), locals: { object: object }
```

With the `find_partial` helper implemented as:

```
def find_partial(name, object)
  [object.class.model_name.plural, 'application'].each do |dir|
    return "#{dir}/#{name.to_s}" if lookup_context.exists?(name.to_s, dir, true)
  end
  raise "Cannot find partial #{name} for #{object}"
end
```